# Pivot Table generation error

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, pivot, pivot-table

I Tried to create a basic pivot table by using pivottable.js.It works fine when I use it as a HTML Page but when I generate it from a servlet or jsp i cannot see the tale beign generated.Could someone help me what I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pivot Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/pivot.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/pivot.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="output" style="margin: 30px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
             var a=[ {"Province": "Quebec", "Party": "NDP"}]
                        $("#output").pivotUI(a);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This Code works fine as it is supposed to,but When I do this from a servlet like below I get a blank screen

```
response.getWriter().println( "<html>");
response.getWriter().println( "<head>");
response.getWriter().println( "<title>Pivot Demo</title>");
response.getWriter().println( "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='D:/pivot.css'>");
            response.getWriter().println( "<script type='text/javascript' src='/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>");
...
...
response.getWriter().println( "$(function(){");
response.getWriter().println( "var a=[ {\"Province\": \"Quebec\", \"Party\": \"NDP\"}]");
response.getWriter().println("$('#output').pivot(a);");
response.getWriter().println( "});");                                   response.getWriter().println( " </script>");                                response.getWriter().println( "<div id='output' style='margin: 30px;'></div>");
```

Comment: If you view the source on the page that is being output by your JSP, does it look the same as the static HTML page that works for you?

Comment: And is there any output in the Javascript console?

Comment: @nicolas I solved the issue i had with the sevlet printing the page,I used the new version of jquery and jqueryUI.But I still have the problem when displaying it in the IE browser.I get the followiung erro in the pivot.js file "Object doesn't support property or method 'isArray' " at line 319 character 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the PivotTable.js library, which I've just fixed.